# ASP.NET empty url parameter causing error unhanded exception in web form aspx

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We are getting a new exception when empty url parameters are passed to a aspx page. the page load is throwing a null reference exception that i would think would be handled by the page load. This is a new issue that just started occurring, what could be happening here?[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading an older application to .net4.6.2.
The problem was an old version of `Microsoft.Security.AntiXssEncoder` in `<httpRuntime>` in web.config, which seems to be incompatible with the new .net version.

I figured out that the AntiXssEncoder library has been moved directly into .net Framework version 4.5.

So I changed the `encoderType` attribute to `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder`.

My httpRuntime tag looks now like this:
`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" requestValidationMode="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder"/>`

More Details: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Remarks